# Symfony form design

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I have an `Event` entity, where entities of `People` can attend. After an event, the host of the event sits down and is supposed to be presented with a form like this.

```
         user a    user b     user c      user d     user e    user f     user g
user a     _
user b               _
user c                          _
user d                                      _
user e                                                 _
user f                                                           _
user g                                                                      _
```

All blanks are checkboxes whether a user likes another user. Underscores are disabled checkboxes, since a user cannot like themselves. Should I use a choice_list? I want to process the input like this:

```
foreach(guests as guest)//horizontal
{
    foreach(guests as other)//vertical
    {
         if(guest != other && guest.likes(other) && other.likes(guest))
         {
             //do something
         }
    }
}
```

How would I use the formbuilder to achieve something like this?

Comment: Do you only need to generate form? Will this form affect any entity? Concretize your problem.

Comment: This form will affect the guest `People` entity. It will not affect the `Event` entity.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't this type of form suits your needs?

```
$userIDsArray = $userIDsArray = array('1' => 'name1','2' => 'name2','3' => 'name3','4' => 'name4');

$form = $this->createFormBuilder($initialData);
    foreach($userIDsArray as $userId)
        $form->add($userId, 'choice', array(
                        'choices' => $userIDsArray,
                        'multiple' => true,
                        'expanded' => true 
                    )
                );
$form = $form->getForm();
```

For this array of users, checking for user 1 all other three users and for user 3 only the forth, will produce a result like this.

```
array (size=4)
  'name1' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => int 2
      1 => int 3
      2 => int 4
  'name2' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'name3' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => int 4
  'name4' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
```

When you render the form you can iterate over every item in form and then for every item you can iterate over every choice and disable the ones you want:

```
{% for formWidget in classForm %}
    {{ form_label(formWidget) }}
    {% for child in formWidget %}
        {{ form_widget(child) }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Of course, you can use differents arrays for rows in form and for choices, implementing the structure you desire.